# Limits with logs

Tags: limits

Find the limit by interpreting the expression as an appropriate derivative.

$$\lim_{w \rightarrow 1} \frac{-8 \ln  w }{w - 1}= ?.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{w\rightarrow1}\dfrac{-8\ln(w)}{w-1}=-8\lim_{w\rightarrow1}\dfrac{\ln(w)}{w-1}$$Now, by using L'Hopital's Rule
$$-8\lim_{w\rightarrow1}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac1w}{1}\right)=-8\lim_{w\rightarrow1}\dfrac1w=-8$$

Comment: wow i feel stupid.. thanks forgot about l'hopital